# rollup.js : How to execute a given module, and returns the result of the execution at build-time?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

How to specify `rollup.js` to execute a given module, and return the result of the execution at build-time ?

Webpack have the `val-loader`

```
  {
    test: require.resolve("src/createConfig.js"),
    use: [
      {
        loader: "val-loader",
        options: {params: "my params"},
      },
    ],
  },
```

E.g. I have the function in createConfig.js:

```
export function createConfig(params) {
  var config = {}
  // dynamically build config from static params, quite verbose code (browse plugins array) 
  return config;
};
```

Then in main.js

```
 import createConfig from "createConfig.js";
 console.log(createConfig); // this shows not a function but object
```

Comment: Webpack now has native functionality that's even better than val-loader: https://twitter.com/agilecoder/status/1611850705614278657

Here is a loader I wrote that takes advantage of this feature, which can address similar use cases as val-loader: http://github.com/nsaunders/execute-module-loader